# One application but different yml files

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 10 applications which runs on the same git tag meaning there is no change in application side what so ever except the config/database.yml which has changes in the database setup.

This consumes a lot of space in the server and I have scalability issues. So, is it possible to have one application cloned and different yml files for the rest 9 instances of the same application. Can a soft link method be applied for this.

Comment: you want to use the same application code for all the applications and  different yml files ..did i get u right?

Comment: @GhostRider: yes exactly

Comment: What exactly consumes so much space? Application code? How much could this be?

Comment: now that I only have 10 applications running in future it may increase to 100. But I don't understand the point of having the same application clone for each and every website but only the database changed. The server space is at stake.

Comment: How about specifying different environments? You have one application source with a set of YML files. These specify settings per environment . Then you can just spin up a new instance of the application for a specific environment.

Comment: @KevinSjöberg: Sounds really interesting can you give me some more sight on how to achieve this. So you mean I will have 10 different yml files for 1 application. How to name these yml files and how to load them on a different URL. 
Now I have something like this: 
/var/www/app1.com/
...
/var/www/app10.com/
each one has the whole application running on the same GIT Tag.

Comment: Have one application source, i.e., /var/www/app.com/. This application the YML files needed. Then you can specify custom environment in which the application can be run. By default Rails have test, development, production. You could specify environments such as app_1, app_2 and so fourth. This may not be the best solution but it's something.

Comment: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Multitenancy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***One application but different yml files***

Just update your database.yml file as given in the question. Suppose our development instances are ***development-1, development-2, development-3 and development-4.***

First you just create 3 copies of the environment file `development-1.rb` (can find insideconfig/environments/) and rename it to `development-2.rb`, `development-3.rb` and `development-4.rb`.

Then, just do run the below steps before starting the servers.

```
RAILS_ENV=development rake db:create 
//(OR just rake db:create as it defaults to development)
RAILS_ENV=development-2 rake db:create
RAILS_ENV=development-3 rake db:create
RAILS_ENV=development-4 rake db:create
```

---

```
RAILS_ENV=development rake db:schema:load 
//(OR just rake db:schema:load as it defaults to development)
RAILS_ENV=development-2 rake db:schema:load
RAILS_ENV=development-3 rake db:schema:load
RAILS_ENV=development-4 rake db:schema:load
```

---

```
RAILS_ENV=development rake db:seed 
//(OR just rake db:seed as it defaults to development)
RAILS_ENV=development-2 rake db:seed
RAILS_ENV=development-3 rake db:seed
RAILS_ENV=development-4 rake db:seed
```

*Then, start all instances with different server pid's as given below.*

```
rails s -p 3000 -e development --pid tmp/pids/server.pid (OR rails s by default)
rails s -p 3002 -e development-2 --pid tmp/pids/server.2.pid
rails s -p 3003 -e development-3 --pid tmp/pids/server.3.pid
rails s -p 3004 -e development-4 --pid tmp/pids/server.4.pid
```

That will start all instances simultaneously from the same source and a single `database.yml` file.

you can also put the connection details in database.yml like usual with a name like so:

***log_database_producion:***

```
adapter: mysql
  host: other_host
  username: logmein
  password: supersecret
  database: logs
```

***Then in your special model:***

```
class AccessLog < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection "log_database_#{Rails.env}"
end
```

***To keep those pesky credentials from being in your application code.***

If you want to reuse this connection in multiple models, you should create a new abstract class and inherit from it, because connections are tightly coupled to classes (as explained here, here, and here), and new connections will be created for each class.

***If that is the case, set things up like so:***

```
class LogDatabase < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  establish_connection "log_database_#{Rails.env}"
end

class AccessLog < LogDatabase
end

class CheckoutLog < LogDatabase
end
```

Ceate a new file in app_1/models folder following the standard Rails naming conventions for a model which in this case would be a file called a_table.rb as it's connecting to a table called a_table then set up the class definition in the standard Rails model format like so

```
class ATable < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

***But how does tha model know to talk to the foreign database?***

All you need to do is add the establish_connection declaration to the class so you end up with

```
class ATable < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection "foreign_#{Rails.env}"
end
```

and just like magick whatever environment you are running app 1 under ATable will be picking up the corresponding environment entries in app 1's database.yml file
e.g. when running in production mode in the above example a_table will automatically connect to the foreign_production entry.

Creating a seperate app I find is overkill for my needs. The application itself will only every have migrations added to it and needs no views, controllers, helpers etc... just a model and the ability to run migrations.

http://archive.railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=42143

http://blog.bitmelt.com/2008/10/connecting-to-multiple-database-in-ruby.html

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/connecting-to-database-on-a-different-server

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/7019

https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html

Answer (score 0):

If im understanding your problem right, 
your issue is just connecting to different database from the same application, in that case you can check for ways to connect multiple dbs from your one master application. Read this

http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/web-development/ruby/9780596510329/database/connecting_to_multiple_databases

There are many gems in Rails that let you do this easily too. Here

https://github.com/cherring/connection_ninja

http://magicmodels.rubyforge.org/magic_multi_connections/

http://rubygems.org/gems/contineo

This way you need to have only one database.yml file and add how many ever databases you want for all your instances.

Hope it helped !

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am aware of connecting to different databases from a sing yml file, but how do I solve the domain name of the website. Each website has a unique domain name. This is configured in /etch/apache2/sites-enabled

Answer (score 0):

If the application logic is the same across all websites then **routes are also the same** and only several ways for distinguish one from another:

1. **use different ports** for each application and corresponding apache/nginx mappings. 
   Here you have to use one running application for every port.

   *www.domain-1.com --> localhost:3001*,
   *www.domain-2.com --> localhost:3002* and etc.

   This is what you have now.
2. **use different controllers** for every site **in one application**. Apache/nginx mapping will map to **only one application**:

   *www.domain-1.com --> localhost:3000*,
   *www.domain-2.com --> localhost:3000* and etc.

   And you could determine appropriate controller in routes.rb (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

   May be something like this:

   **routes.rb:**

   ```
   require 'domain'
   constraints(Domain) do
     match '/' => 'controller-1#action'
   end
   ```

   **concerns/domain.rb:**

   ```
   class Domain
     def self.matches?(request)
       request.domain.present? && request.domain == "www.domain-1.com"
     end
   end
   ```

   As for yml files, you could just a merge them into one application too.